# Why can't you downvote a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

This is in reference to [Can the multiplication of two unsigned shorts really lead to undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785566/can-the-multiplication-of-two-unsigned-shorts-really-lead-to-undefined-behaviour)

Here, at the time of writing, there is the comment:

> no, it's defined behavior (witch [sic] becomes same value as
>   (i*j)%std::numeric_limits::max()) without consider [sic]
>   overflow

1. This is in contradiction to the heavily upvoted answer
2. It's an answer masquerading as a comment
3. It has a probably unintentional upvote
4. It is of rather poor quality (bad spelling, punctuation)

If comments were able to be downvoted, then it could assist the peer review process.

Or am I wrong?